# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts exception

Tags: mysql, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, entity-framework-core, dockerfile

So I have created asp.net core web API 6.0 project its a simple project and my goal was to get used to docker containers. So I added dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml file in my project. when I run this project it is creating containers for my app and for server also. but when I try to make a call on my endpoint it returns an error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."
also I want mention that if I run this project on IIS express the endpoints are working as expected without any error.So I guess the problem is with my docker configurations but Im not sure what exactly is the problem I've researched everywhere but couldn't found anything that could help my problem. here is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3'

volumes:
    datafiles:

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.0
        volumes:
          - datafiles:/var/lib/mysql  
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mat12345678
    api: 
     build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
     depends_on: 
        - db 
     ports:
        - "8888:80" 
     restart: always
     environment: 
        - DBHOST=db
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

and here is dockerfile

```
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /AggregationApp
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /AggregationApp
COPY ["AggregationApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "AggregationApp.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "AggregationApp.csproj" -c Release -o /AggregationApp/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AggregationApp.csproj" -c Release -o /AggregationApp/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /AggregationApp
COPY --from=publish /AggregationApp/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AggregationApp.dll"]`
```

any help would be appriciated.I will provied more information if needed.
also here is the stack trace

at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 432
at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 363
at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 94
at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 124
at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken

I dont understand what exactly is the problem here because as I already mentioned I used docker for the first time I tried to conigure docker-compose file differenctly but didnt get any result

Comment: Can you add the _connectionstring_ do you use on the ASP.NET app?

Comment: yeah I use ASP.NET. this is my connectionstring 
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=MyDB;Uid=sa;Pwd=mypwd;"

Answer (score 0):

You miss the MySQL Server name

```json
"ConnectionStrings": 
     { "DefaultConnection": "Server=db;Database=MyDB;Uid=sa;Pwd=mypwd;" }
```

See the [networking in compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#:%7E:text=Each%20container%20can%20now%20look%20up%20the%20hostname%20web%20or%20db%20and%20get%20back%20the%20appropriate%20container%E2%80%99s%20IP%20address.%20For%20example%2C%20web%E2%80%99s%20application%20code%20could%20connect%20to%20the%20URL%20postgres%3A//db%3A5432%20and%20start%20using%20the%20Postgres%20database.)